# Algorithm to find phase boundaries

Tags: hubbard-model, phase-transitions, phase-diagram, computational-frameworks

I am looking for an algorithm/library to find phase boundaries as a function of some parameters. E.g. in the Hubbard model, the phase diagram as a function of U and doping hosts metal/insulator transitions. Suppose I have a code that can determine the phase at any arbitrary point in the phase diagram (e.g. takes U and doping as input, solves the model, and returns the gap). I want to find the entire domain where the system metallic. Is there some algorithm that, given an initial point, can tell me which direction to go in the phase diagram to find the phase boundary, and then follow the phase boundary around the domain?

I suppose I could minimize the gap wrt U and doping, but if the initial point is in the metallic phase, this wont help.

Thanks!
Ty